# Abstract analysis

Tags: historical-linguistics, analysis

Propose two analyses for given data: an abstract analysis, with abstract underlying segments and a concrete analysis with exception features.

[sen't-amos]   we sit  /           ['sjent-o] I sit

[kon't-amos]   we count / ['kwent-o] I count

[ben'd-amos]    we sell / ['bend-o] I sell

[mon'tamos] we mount / ['mont-o] I mount

[alje'n-amos]  we alienate / [a'ljen-o]I alienate

[frekwen't-amos] we frequent  / [fre'kwent-o] I frequent

So far I have these things:

surface alteration         /                     underlying form

non-alternation [e] or [o]                   /            [e] or [o]

non-alternation [je] or [we]                 /             [je] or [we]

[e] or [o] alternating with [je] or [we]/                 ?

we have these alternations under the stress situation.

Now I have a question are these analyses correct? what are abstract underlying segments? how about concrete analysis with exception features?

Comment: What problem would that be? Are you supposed to write rules to delete word-final *mos*?

Comment: actually I mentioned these final words just because of the stress issue. The problem is I can not write  concrete analysis with exception features. and also what are abstract underlying segments?

Comment: An abstract segment is a segment that does not appear phonetically in any instantiation of the morpheme. A so-called "concrete" analysis assumes underlying forms that are either composed of segments that appear in some surface allomorph of the morpheme, or some actual surface allomorph. A completely concrete analysis does not distinguish underlying and surface representations.

Comment: would you please give me one examle of "abstract underlying segment" of above date?

Comment: For example *frekwento* ← /freqento/. Or, ← /frekænto/. There are very many abstract analyses.

Comment: Actually, this problem is the chapter 12 Introductory phonology By Bruce Hayesexcerise. If it is helpful to understand what I really need to answer this exercise.

Comment: What is the question actually asking? Why all of the six rules exist?

Comment: [Related wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underlying_representation)

Comment: These data are consistent with a fully-concrete ("some surface allomorph") non-exceptional analysis. Spanish has diphthongs, end of story. What is the point of adding exception features?

Comment: I don't know what would be the point of adding exception features. This is what writer wants, I have no idea.

Comment: What does this have to do with historical linguistics? What language is it?

Comment: This is a homework problem: Spanish diphthongization.

Comment: This is not a homework problem, I am reading Introductory phonology book and cannot solve this exercise. As you might understand, I do not live in he USA and I cannot find a knowledgeable person in my country which our native language is not English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I am answering the question.

When Spanish was evolving very early (600AD plus or minus 400 years), a process called "vowel breaking" occured, which basically turned *some* [o] into [we], and *some* [e] into [je], when they are stressed. The evolution is something like as follows:

- `Latin: computáre, cómputo (accent for stress)`
- `[kombu'tare], ['kombuto]`
- `[komb'tar], ['kombto]`
- `[kom'tar], ['kwemto]`
- `[kon'tar], ['kwento]`
- `Modern Spanish: contar, cuento`

Since it happened too early, modern speakers would not have `['konto]` as the underlying form of `['kwento]`.

However, if you had to impose an underlying form, it would be `['konto]`.

In general, *some* `[e]` and `[o]` in **stressed** positions change to `[je]` and `[we]` respectively.

---

#### abstract analysis (my attempt)

Some `[e]` and `[o]` change to `[je]` and `[we]` when stressed. Some don't change when stressed. Some are `[je]` and `[we]` overall.

The `[e]` and `[o]` that change must have a different underlying representation than those that do not change. Perhaps those that change are lower than others, i.e. `[ɛ]` and `[ɔ]`.

Moreover, those `[je]` and `[we]` can keep those as their underlying representations.

```
Underlying representation | surface form
[sɛn't-amos]              | [sen't-amos]
['sɛnt-o]                 | ['sjent-o]
[kɔn't-amos]              | [kon't-amos]
['kɔnt-o]                 | ['kwent-o]
[ben'd-amos]              | [ben'd-amos]
['bend-o]                 | ['bend-o]
[mon'tamos]               | [mon'tamos]
['mont-o]                 | ['mont-o]
[alje'n-amos]             | [alje'n-amos]
[a'ljen-o]                | [a'ljen-o]
[frekwen't-amos]          | [frekwen't-amos]
[fre'kwent-o]             | [fre'kwent-o]
```

---

#### concrete analysis (my attempt)

`[e]` and `[o]` when stressed becomes `[je]` and `[we]` except `monto` and `vendo`.

Comment: You might want to consider a phenomenon known as rule-inversion where earlier a → b / __ c becomes b → a / __ ~c.

Comment: Please do refine my answer by editing it directly.